# How to create a dict of lists in as little coding as possible in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dict of lists where the key is a variable from a function that I call (to return an object). I then want to create a list of those objects. I have a hard time instantiating the list without cumbersome code. Can someone show me how to do this more efficiently?

Here is my current code:

```
def test(xlist):
    ret = dict()
    for x in xlist:
        y = somefunction(x)
        if y.variable not in ret:
            ret[y.variable] = [y]
        else:
            ret[y.variable].append(y)

    return ret
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:  That's quite an accusation.  Would you offer some support for it?

Comment: I'm guessing because it contains at least one syntax error? `append(y]`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath:  If Marein is correct, your comment would have been *much* more helpful if you gave the reason.  That gives TheBear an opportunity to fix the question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I prefer to make people *think*. But I guess, some people just don't want to...

Comment: Let's keep stackoverflow a positive and open place for people to ask questions. Someone has provided a great answer, so case closed. Many thanks for all your inputs!!!

Comment: Many thanks Steven, I have amended the question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don;t need a membership check before inserting so as not to override duplicate element. Either you can use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Instead of

```
    if y.variable not in ret:
        ret[y.variable] = [y]
    else:
        ret[y.variable].append(y)
```

rewrite it as

```
    ret.setdefault(y.variable,[]).append(y)
```

In case you are interested to use default dict, this is what you may like to do

```
def test(xlist):
    from collections import defaultdict
    ret = defaultdict(list)
    for x in xlist:
        y = somefunction(x)
        ret[y.variable].append(y)
    return ret
```